# Resize label to fit text amount - Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uilabel

Hey :) I have a label and I need to make the width of that label smaller or larger accourding to the text amount, and I found only how to adjust the text to fit the size but the how to adjust the size to fit the text, any ideas ?

Answer (score 58):

You'll want to do this:

```
myLabel.sizeToFit()
```

As seen here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622630-sizetofit

This will update the label's frame to fit the content. You can then place it or make any edits after this that you want.

Comment: how would I go about spacing the content of the label so that it automatically changes rows instead of just outputting a long string of text onto one line?

Comment: This workes well together with "myLabel.numberOfLines = 0"

Answer (score 12):

**sizeToFit()** doesn't always work so you should use this:

```
myLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
myLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
myLabel.numberOfLines = 1
```

Or if you don't have limit lines you can do this:

```
myLabel.numberOfLines = 0
```

Comment: you should add 
`myLabel.numberOfLines = 1 `
to your answer, so the minimumScaleFactor works

Comment: @JoãoSerra Eu vou adicionar 

Answer (score 7):

Here's the step that work in mine:

1. Set **width** constraint to the label, then **click the constraint**.
2. Select **Size Inspector**.
3. Set the **relation** to **less than or equal**, and set **max width**.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> myLabelName.numberOfLines = 0

** This worked for me ( To put Same Text Size, this will put text to a new line on width size reduced) **

##### We can also use,

> myLabelName.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
> myLabelName.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5

** This will reduce size of the text on width size reduced. **

Answer (score 1):

you can set 
[lines: 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IL4tA.png)
, hope its helps.

Comment: Please consider adding a short explanation on hao that helps the OP and where can he do the change that you mentioned here

Answer (score 1):

Many of the above responses work well, but you have to consider the `UILabel`'s constraints.

For example, if you ensure that the `UILabel` will have **leadingAnchor** and **trailingAnchor** Constraints with its superview, you can use the `.numberOfLines = 0` property, and the height content size will be set automatically.

Answer (score -1):

I had a somewhat different case unrelated to `sizeToFit()`. My label had `adjustFontSizeToFitWidth = true` and it was oddly adjusting the font size when it did not need to *and* leaving the label with extra padding at the end.

Simple fix:

```
myLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
```