# Resize label to fit value

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

I'm trying to resize label to fit text amount but the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31592272/resize-label-to-fit-text-amount-swift) needs a bit more explanation.

For me, I have three labels: currency, integer amount, double amount:

[image]

I have three labels due to the fact that both currency and double amount have different style than of the integer amount. If I'm going this the wrong way, please to correct me as I could not have just one label for all three.

All three have an autoresizing of `top-right`

Eventually I have to remove the static values but when I apply the code below, noting works:

**viewDidLoad() or viewDidAppear():**

```
integerAmountLabel.sizeToFit()

integerAmountLabel.text = "1"
// or integerAmountLabel = "280,000"
```

Expectation: `£1.00` or `£280,000.00`. What I got: `£1    .00` or `£     1.00`

Comment: Are you using `autoLayout`?

Comment: @Rikh Yes I am.

Comment: First set the text to the lable and then call sizeToFit method on label.

Comment: Can you explain what constraints you are using? Ought to explain why that is the case.

Comment: @Rikh No constraints on the labels. Let me try what devgr said.

Comment: Use single UILabel and by using NSAttributedString apply style based on the range of string.This will solve the complexity of applying constaints.

Comment: @devgr Does not work. Its the same. The `£` and `1` are stacked together. When I drag a label onto the the storyboard, do I stretch it or not?

Comment: You  should definitely add constraints to ensure your `UILabel` resizes properly. Or as @user3608500 suggests you can use `NSAttributedString` but i honestly consider that to be more difficult than settings constraints.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a play then state what works.

Comment: Why not to upgrade it with a UIStackView? It will help you better than auto layout in this case setting horizontal as flow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Aman Gupta mentioned already, use attributed strings. Here's a playground snippet explaining how to do it:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

var str = "Hello, playground"

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 300))
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view

// set up view hierarchy
view.backgroundColor = .blue
let label = UILabel()
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(label)
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[label]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0), metrics: nil, views: ["label": label]))
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[label]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0), metrics: nil, views: ["label": label]))

// set up atributes
let currencyAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20), NSForegroundColorAttributeName:  UIColor.white]
let integerAmountAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
let decimalAmountAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.7)]


// set up formatter
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.currency
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")

let amount = 8001.9
let text = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: amount))!
let nsText = text as NSString

// calculate ranges
let currencyRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: 1)
let decimalPointRange = nsText.range(of: ".")
var integerAmountLocation = currencyRange.location + currencyRange.length
var integerAmountLength = decimalPointRange.location - integerAmountLocation
var integerAmountRange = NSRange(location: integerAmountLocation, length: integerAmountLength)

// configure attributed string
var attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: decimalAmountAttributes)
attributedText.setAttributes(currencyAttributes, range: currencyRange)
attributedText.setAttributes(integerAmountAttributes, range: integerAmountRange)

label.attributedText = attributedText
```

[image: Result]

You can get the entire playground here: https://github.com/AleksanderMaj/AttributedString

Comment: Yes sir. I'll accept this one. Very useful. I may need to create few constants as I'll need to reuse, for example, `currencyAttributes` elsewhere.

Comment: Foundation has a NumberFormatter class that simplifies formatting currencies and makes it locale-dependent.

`NumberFormatter.Style.currency`

I'll update the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single label, this will solve all your problems and also you will not have to compromise with your label styles.This can be achieved by using **NSAttributedString**. An Example is shown below with the output you can refer that.

```
    let string = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "1000.12")
    string.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName,value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25.0), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 4))
    string.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName,value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10.0), range: NSRange(location: 5, length: 2))
```

[image]

Comment: How exactly do I set this to the label?

Comment: simply by using the attributedText property of UILabel you can set this to the label..for instance 
label.attributedText = string

Comment: I cant get the small `.12` because I have set a font size on the label

Comment: see the thing is the attributed property that we are setting applies for the text in the range i.e. NSRange(location: 0,length: 4).You can add more than one attribute by the same methods just change the range of the. I am also updating the answer accordingly please refer.

Comment: Done what you've stated but my `.12` is still huge. Have you actually tried this?

Comment: hey there was an issue in typing the font size i have changed it now.please consider